# Calling an Asset from the Assets.xcassets folder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It seems that an asset within my Assets.xcassets folder cannot be found. I'm getting the error [Use of unresolved identifier]. Am I calling it the right way?

```
        if buttonName.currentImage == imageName { // etc…
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file names in your assets folder are not variables too. If you want to get the image from a file, you must say `UIImage(named: "moreOff")`.

Instead of directly comparing the current image, you should add a boolean state variable to your class. For example, `var isMoreOff: Bool`. Whenever you change the image, you must update `isMoreOff` accordingly.

Comment: Making decisions based on some artwork that you are using is very bad style. Have a bool property that indicates the state, then set the image according to that property. Comparing images is _difficult_.

Comment: @gnasher729 good point. I don't know what I was thinking! Edited.